# How to show next article on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide and show different articles on click of a button. This is like step by step instruction. Here I have the code block below

```
<article class="content-1">Content 1
    <button type="button" class="continue">Continue</button>
</article>
<article class="content-2">Content 2
    <button type="button" class="continue">Continue</button>
</article>
<article class="content-3">Content 3
    <button type="button" class="continue">Continue</button>
</article>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.continue').click(function()
    $(this).parents('div').next('article').show();
});
```

Now on click of the `.continue` `button` I need to hide the present article and show the next article. Can anyone help me out to solve this thanks in advance.

Note: Reaching the last `article` should stop the function.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/kaqr6ysn/11/)**

Comment: Please include the JS code you've written in your question and fiddle.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan jquery updated

Comment: You're looking for a `div` that doesn't exist.

Comment: @rybo111 sorry doesnt updated my fiddle

Comment: @rybo111 fiddle updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your js. You can try following:

```
$('.continue').click(function () {

    if ($(this).parent("article").next().length > 0) { //check if there is more articles
        $(this).parent("article").next().show(); //show next article
        $(this).parent("article").hide(); //hide present article
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kaqr6ysn/39/)

Comment: That great but i need one it reaches the final article i need to stop the function.

Comment: I did the same for `prev` `$(this).parents('article').hide().prev().show();` and its not working anymore. Could you assist me.

Comment: Do you mean you create another button to go to previous?

Comment: Yep just a back button for ma page

Comment: Oh i notice that button is universal it dont lean on any article it stick to its parent section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61334/discussion-between-alek-and-benjamin).

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/kaqr6ysn/4/

You could quite simply do this:

```
$('button.continue').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
});
```

You haven't explained what to do at the end, though. Presumably you will omit the continue button from the last `article`?

---

Update: if you're wondering why your fiddle didn't work:

- You didn't select jQuery on the fiddle
- You omitted the `{` from line 1
- You referenced `div` rather than `article` on line 2
- You neglected to `.hide()` the article

Comment: Once it reaches last article it should stop its function.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just omit the button from the final article.

Comment: Thanks for spotted the errors I made that does the trick. I owe you really.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with this solution:

I have changed some css and html markup classes

Changed class name, added common class name

```
<article class="content">Content 1
    <button type="button" class="continue">Continue</button>
</article>
```

use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find nearest parent.

```
$(".continue").on("click",function(){
    if($(this).closest(".content").next(".content").length > 0){
       $(this).closest(".content").hide();
       $(this).closest(".content").next(".content").show();
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.content:not(:first-of-type) {
    display:none;
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kaqr6ysn/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this : hide all article first then find next article to show it, if next article not present then stop the function.

```
$(function(){
    $('.continue').click(function(){

      var next = $(this).closest('article').next();
      //check if next article is present or not
        if(next.length!=0)
        {
            $('.continue').closest('article').hide();
            next.show();
        }
     });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaqr6ysn/24/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `closest()` to get the parent article. Then you can use `.next()` in with `.hide()`

*Script*

```
$('.continue').on('click', function(){
    var article = $(this).closest('article');    
    if(article.next('article').length){
        article.next('article').show();
    }else{
        $('article').first().show(); //If you want to use continuous loop use it else just delete this line
    }    
    article.hide()
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2ph4k48a/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
$('button').click(function(){
var ar = $(this).parent('article');
if (ar.next().length)
{
    ar.hide().next().show();
 }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaqr6ysn/19/)